# Central Limit Theorem + Slutsky Theorem For Confidence Intervals

Tags: confidence-interval

If n is large enough to justify the Central Limit Theorem, then we have the pivotal quantity:

$$\mathbb{P} \Bigg( - z_{\alpha/2} \leqslant \frac{\bar{X} - \mu}{\sigma / \sqrt{n}} \leqslant z_{\alpha/2} \Bigg) \approx 1- \alpha.$$

Rewriting it to get in the form of Confidence Intervals:

$$\mathbb{P} \Bigg( \bar{X} - \frac{z_{\alpha/2}}{\sqrt{n}} \cdot \sigma \leqslant \mu \leqslant \bar{X} + \frac{z_{\alpha/2}}{\sqrt{n}} \cdot \sigma  \Bigg) \approx 1- \alpha.$$

And with the Slutsky Theorem we can swap $\sigma$ with the estimated standard deviation.

However, I've heard that it's not as good as estimating a Confidence Interval with Bootstrap (Percentile Bootstrapping Method for example).

Are there any references for this? Or simulations?

Or maybe is it simply *not true*?

Comment: It may depend on questions like: "better" in what sense? How large is $n$ to be "large enough"? Is each $X_i$ iid normal?

Comment: better in the sense of do we have a good coverage (around 95% of true population parameter in the estimated intervals if we draw a million samples of size $n$ and build a million confidence intervals if we are building 95% confidence intervals)

Comment: and do we have scientists that estimated how large n should be enough for us to have a coverage between 94.5% et 95.5% for example